# Откуда лишние символы во входном потоке?

Tags: c, кодировка, gcc

Начал изучать C по книжке "Язык программирования C" (Керниган и Ритчи). И столкнулся с проблемой: написал программу, которая из входного потока копирует посимвольно все в выходной. Но программа добавляет от себя какие-то кракозябры. Вот скрин:

[image]

И вторая, наверное, родственная, проблема. Программа подсчета символов тоже очень врет. Скрин:

[image]

Компилирую все с помощью *gcc*, без параметров.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Sublime`, как я посмотрю, теперь стоит у каждого второго.

Comment: Ну удобный редактор, что ж не поставить =)

Comment: @Azat Galiev, у меня в той ветке комментарии кончились (на форуме лимит 4 шт.) поэтому продолжаю здесь.

Вы пишите

    Все нормально, и так, и так корректно выводит.

1. Означает ли это, что проблема с UTF-8 *в системном терминале* пропала ?

2. По поводу UTF (подсчет символов) можете ознакомиться в [статье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (IMHO ее предыдущий вариант был намного лучше).

Comment: Не думаю так. И заметил, еще, что на одни и те же строки обе программы реагируют по разному. Иногда - выводит без кракозябр. Ну, и, иногда циферок поменьше. Хотя, все равно много. Ну, сейчас статью прочту, разберусь, надеюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: @Azat Galiev, насчет `getchar()` и полбуквы кириллицы правильно. По поводу "не видим этого" - не совсем Вас понял.

"Терминал" читает поток байт и рассматривает их как кодтровку UTF-8. Если байт ASCII (от 0 до 0x7f), то он выводитя его изображение. Иначе терминал читает несколько байт, составляющих правильный код Unicode символа, закодированного в UTF-8. Не все комбинации допустимы. Неправильная (в смысле UTF-8) последователььность будет отображаться спец. символом (что Вы и видите).

Проблема в том, что Ваша программа копирования **правильная**. Откуда "грязь" не понятно.

Comment: Кстати, я проверил первую программу в gnome-terminal и других эмуляторах терминала. Все работает правильно.

Comment: Я тоже глазам не поверил и проверил в нескольких эмуляторах. Даже тот же русский текст вбивал. Все работает.

Comment: Ну, значит, что-то у меня с терминалом... @avp, ну я это и подразумевал =) Всем спасибо!

Comment: @Azat Galiev Вероятно проблемы терминала. Перед появлением крякозябр, Вы нажимали Backspace?

Comment: Да, сейчас попробовал, похоже, это из-за BS.

Comment: Тогда можете с настройками stty (man stty) покопаться. Обычно его ставят в CANONIC mode и тогда управляющие символы в программу не попадают.

@alexlz, Вам плюс.

Answer (score 4):

Второй вопрос решается очень просто. В Ubuntu используется кодировка UTF-8, которая для кириллицы использует 2 байта на символ. Вы же подсчитываете число байтов в считанной строке.

Comment: Да, а первый случай загадка.

@Azat Galiev, попробуйте запустить из системного терминала, а не IDE.

Comment: Это и есть системный терминал.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте запустить xterm и пробуйте в нем. 

Еще один вариант 

    ./a.out < main.c

Что получилось ? 

Это я про **первый случай**. Второй очевиден (@mikillskegg разъяснил его Вам).

Comment: Вы считываете из stdin не символы, а байты. И их же считаете.

Comment: [Тут](http://s018.radikal.ru/i511/1208/ee/42431f30e44a.png), вроде, все ok.

Comment: И правильно. Для латиницы в UTF-8 1 байт/символ.

Comment: Похоже. Так что у Вас с набором символов в xterm?

Кстати, с ascii такая же петрушка,, как с русским?

Дело в том, что программа правильная.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. Поставил ASCII (CP1251), все, вроде, норм...

Comment: @Azat Galiev, с CP1251 все норм. - это понятно. Непонятно, потему проблемы с UTF-8.

У меня в xubuntu 12.04 LTS (терминал xfce4-terminal) все ОК. В другой убунте (11.04) тоже ничего подобного не замечал.

Загадка. Попробуйте набить файл (в UTF-8) в редакторе и вывести на экран его командой cat, а потом вашей программой. Что получится?

Comment: Все нормально, и так, и так корректно выводит.